# Difference between isPresent and isElementPresent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protractor

What's the difference between [ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent) and [ElementFinder.prototype.isElementPresent](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isElementPresent)?

It sounds like `isElementPresent` waits for Angular to finish, while `isPresent` just does a check immediately, but I can't tell for sure.

Currently, `isElementPresent` is broken as per a [Protractor bug](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1658), so I can't manually test the difference.

Comment: Oops, perhaps it isn't broken, but I was using it wrong. It looks like `isElementPresent` is expecting a locator as a parameter. It will then return `true` if there is more than one child element matching the locator - I think. I could definitely use verification though.

Comment: Hi @mitchell, please consider marking my answer 'accepted'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `isPresent` and `isElementPresent` return an ["Element Finder"](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder) which:

> "represents a single element of an ElementArrayFinder (and is more like a convenience object). As a result, anything that can be done with an ElementFinder, can also be done using an ElementArrayFinder. The ElementFinder can be treated as a WebElement for most purposes, in particular, you may perform actions (i.e. click, getText) on them as you would a WebElement."

Reader's Digest version: You can call methods on it or test if it exists.

`isElementPresent` actually calls `isPresent` if the locator is met, see the return statement:
[image]

They essentially do the same thing. Protractor is built on top of [WebDriver](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver), which has its own methods. You can also use these methods in Protractor. In the event that testing Angular with these methods could result in faulty information, they provided users with an Angular work-around; `isElementPresent` is one of those, for the reason you mentioned.

**tl;dr:** Use `isPresent`. It was built for Protractor to test Angular.